# Benefit of LinkedList

Tags: java, algorithm, linked-list

From this [link](https://sites.google.com/site/jeff00coder00seattle/home/general-programming-knowledge/interview-questions/interview-questions-set-one#TOC-What-s-the-difference-between-a-linked-list-and-an-array-):

> The principal benefit is that the order of the linked items may be
>   different from the order that the data items are stored in memory or
>   on disk, allowing the list of items to be traversed in a different
>   order.

Is anybody able to explain the concept quoted above in other words? I cannot quite grasp it.

Comment: I dont believe that is quite the principal benefit.

Comment: It's nonsense, basically. Ignore it. The principal benefits is the constant time insertion and deletion, IMO.

Comment: Welcome to SO.  StackOverflow is for questions relating directly to code you have written.  It is generally not a tutorial site.  Please read the [FAQ] and [Ask] for details.  That said, that quote is meaningless and misleading.  Ignore it.

Comment: I'd say the major advantage of a linkedlist is the way the nodes are structured and thus allow for easy adding and removing. But that's a different discussion.

Comment: Couldn't we cite the possibility of size increase without need of reallocating previous elements (in contrast to `ArrayList`)?

Comment: possible duplicate of [When to use LinkedList<> over ArrayList<>?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/322715/when-to-use-linkedlist-over-arraylist)

Comment: This quote is nonsense, at least it is not the main benefit.

Answer (score 0):

Benefits of LinkedList:

1.In a linked list, insertions and deletions can be handled efficiently without fixing the size of the memory in advance. Much faster then other data structures ex linked list insertion speed is much faster then a arraylist.

2.An important advantage of linked lists over arrays is that the linked list uses exactly as much memory as it needs, and can be made to expand to fill all available memory locations if needed.

on other hand Linked list also come with some cost for example it has a worst traversal speed because of sequential order of searching.